# Sorting vector of pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm having a little trouble trying to sort a vector of pointers.

This is what I have done so far:

```
class Node
{
    private:
    vector <Node*> _children;
    string _data;
    ...
    public:
    void Node::add_child(Node* child)
    {
        ...
        sort(_children.begin(), _children.end());
    }

    bool Node::operator<(const Node& node)
    {
        return (this->_data.compare(node._data) == -1);
    }
};
```

My less-than operator works, if I write like this:

```
Node* root = new Node("abc");
Node* n = new Node("def");
cout << (*root<*n) << endl;
```

Why does sort never call the operator?? Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

madshov

Comment: Thanks guys I got it now. /mads

Comment: Did you solve your own problem?

Answer (score 33):

Because you sort the pointer values, not the `Node`s they point to.

You can use the third argument of the [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) algorithm to specify a custom comparator.

For example :

```
bool comparePtrToNode(Node* a, Node* b) { return (*a < *b); }

std::sort(_children.begin(), _children.end(), comparePtrToNode);
```

(note that this code is just an indication - you'll have to add extra safety checks where needed)

Answer (score 14):

Your less-than operator takes `const Node&` arguments, but your vector is sorting `Node*`s. You need to specify a comparison function as the third parameter to `std::sort`.

```
class Node
{
    private:
    vector <Node*> _children;
    string _data;
    struct PointerCompare {
      bool operator()(const Node* l, const Node* r) {
        return *l < *r;
      }
    };
    public:
    void add_child(Node* child)
    {
        sort(_children.begin(), _children.end(), PointerCompare());
    }

    bool operator<(const Node& node) const
    {
        return (this->_data.compare(node._data) == -1);
    }
};
```

Also, your `operator<` needs to be declared `const`.

Comment: Arguably, `PointerCompare` could just be a static function.

Comment: The result of using `operator<()` to compare pointers is generally unspecified as per [expr.rel/2]: _"If two pointers p and q of the same type point to different objects that are not members of the same
object or elements of the same array or to different functions, or if only one of them is null, the results
of p<q, p>q, p<=q, and p>=q are unspecified."_

You may use `std::less<const Node*>()` instead of `PointerCompare` to achieve this.

Comment: @boycy - 1) My example never compares pointers. 2) `std::less<const Node*>()` **does** compare pointers, and thus invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Robᵩ Erk sorry, my bad - being too hasty. FWIW `std::less<T*>` doesn't invoke UB as it has a partial specialization that provides well-defined total order for pointers regardless of `operator<()` (ditto the other 3 comparators) [N3337 20.8.6/8]

Comment: @boycy - Thanks! I didn't know that `std::less` was defined for pointer types.

Comment: No worries, I thought a freebie was in order since you refrained from calling me a muppet ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Your `operator<()` operates on references to `Node` objects; but the vector contains *pointers* to `Node` objects, which can't be compared with that function. You'll have to explicitly supply a proper function (one that accepts pointers as arguments) to the `sort()` algorithm.