# How can can I sort a vector of pointed-to values using std::sort()?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, pointers

There is already the post [sorting vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446743/sorting-vector-of-pointers) but this is not about a vector of pointers but rather about a vector of referencing pointers.

3 integer are put into a `std::vector<int*>` which is than sorted according to the values behind the pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 1;

    std::vector<int*> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(&a);
    vec.emplace_back(&b);
    vec.emplace_back(&c);

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const int* a, const int* b) {
        return *a < *b;
    });

    std::cout << "vec = " << *vec[0] << ", " << *vec[1] << ", " << *vec[2] << '\n';
    std::cout << "abc = " << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << '\n';
}
```

however, it seems that only the vector was sorted as the output shows:

```
vec = 1, 2, 3 
abc = 3, 2, 1
```

I think the reason is that `std::sort()`, while comparing correctly, simply assigns adresses instead of the values. What is wrong here? Why can't I sort this vector of pointed-to values?

The next part is rather TL,DR as it shows my approach to solve this. An easy task that reveals itself to be rather frustratingly complicated. [@Bathsheba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55594375/how-can-i-sort-a-vector-of-pointers-by-value-using-stdsort/55594790#55594790) points out that **it is not possible**. So the next parts, initially considered to be the presentation of my attempt, might now be considered to be the reason *why* it is not possible.

---

My idea is to make a pointer class wrapper to provide my own contructors and assignement operators. `std::sort()` behaves differently if the size of the container is small (`<= 32` on my system) but in both cases there are assignements and moves happening - as this small snippet from the `_Insertion_sort_unchecked` (from `<algorithm>`) function shows.

(`_BidIt` == `std::vector<int*>::iterator` and `_Iter_value_t<_BidIt>` == `int*`)

```
_BidIt _Insertion_sort_unchecked(_BidIt _First, const _BidIt _Last, _Pr _Pred)
    {   // insertion sort [_First, _Last), using _Pred
    if (_First != _Last)
        {
        for (_BidIt _Next = _First; ++_Next != _Last; )
            {   // order next element
            _BidIt _Next1 = _Next;
            _Iter_value_t<_BidIt> _Val = _STD move(*_Next);

            if (_DEBUG_LT_PRED(_Pred, _Val, *_First))
                {   // found new earliest element, move to front
                _Move_backward_unchecked(_First, _Next, ++_Next1);
                *_First = _STD move(_Val);
```

Let's make a class `assignement_pointer` that behaves like a pointer except that it assigns the values instead of the adresses.

```
template<typename T>
class assignement_pointer {
public:
    assignement_pointer(T& value) {
        this->m_ptr = &value;
        std::cout << "<T>& constructor\n";
    }
    assignement_pointer(const assignement_pointer& other) {
        this->m_ptr = other.m_ptr;
        std::cout << "copy constructor\n";
    }
    assignement_pointer(assignement_pointer&& other) {
        std::cout << "move assignement constructor >> into >> ";
        *this = std::move(other);
    }
    assignement_pointer& operator=(const assignement_pointer& other) {
        *this->m_ptr = *other.m_ptr;
        std::cout << "copy assignement operator\n";
        return *this;
    }
    assignement_pointer& operator=(assignement_pointer&& other) {
        std::swap(this->m_ptr, other.m_ptr);
        std::cout << "move assignement operator\n";
        return *this;
    }
    T& operator*() {
        return *this->m_ptr;
    }
    const T& operator*() const {
        return *this->m_ptr;
    }
private:
    T* m_ptr;
};
```

As you can see there are also temporary `std::cout`'s to see which constructors / assignement operators were called while going through `std::sort()` in the main:

```
    ///...
    std::vector<assignement_pointer<int>> vec;
    vec.reserve(3);
    vec.emplace_back(assignement_pointer(a));
    vec.emplace_back(assignement_pointer(b));
    vec.emplace_back(assignement_pointer(c));

    std::cout << "\nsort()\n";
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const assignement_pointer<int>& a, const assignement_pointer<int>& b) {
        return *a < *b;
    });

    std::cout << "\nvec = " << *vec[0] << ", " << *vec[1] << ", " << *vec[2] << '\n';
    std::cout << "abc = " << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << '\n';
```

giving the output:

```
<T>& constructor
move assignement constructor >> into >> move assignement operator
<T>& constructor
move assignement constructor >> into >> move assignement operator
<T>& constructor
move assignement constructor >> into >> move assignement operator

sort()
move assignement constructor >> into >> move assignement operator
move assignement operator
move assignement operator
move assignement constructor >> into >> move assignement operator
move assignement operator
move assignement operator
move assignement operator

vec = 1, 2, 3
abc = 3, 2, 1
```

- `std::sort()` calls only move functions.
- again, `vec` is sorted but not `a`, `b`, `c`

the last point makes sense, because since only move functions are called the copy assignement operator `assignement_pointer& operator=(const assignement_pointer& other);` (which does the value assignement) is never called. The unnecessary copy constructor and assignement operator can be removed:

```
template<typename T>
class assignement_pointer {
public:
    assignement_pointer(T& value) {
        this->m_ptr = &value;
    }
    assignement_pointer(const assignement_pointer& other) = delete;
    assignement_pointer& operator=(const assignement_pointer& other) = delete;
    assignement_pointer(assignement_pointer&& other) {
        std::cout << "move assignement constructor >> into >> ";
        *this = std::move(other);
    }
    assignement_pointer& operator=(assignement_pointer&& other) {
        std::swap(this->m_ptr, other.m_ptr);
        std::cout << "move assignement operator\n";
        return *this;
    }
    T& operator*() {
        return *this->m_ptr;
    }
    const T& operator*() const {
        return *this->m_ptr;
    }
private:
    T* m_ptr;
};
```

Now `std::sort()` inner processes are rather complicated but in the end it comes down to failing at an operation like `std::swap()`:

```
 int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int b = 2;

    std::vector<assignement_pointer<int>> vec;
    vec.reserve(2); //to avoid re-allocations
    vec.emplace_back(assignement_pointer(a));
    vec.emplace_back(assignement_pointer(b));

    std::cout << "swap()\n";

    assignement_pointer<int> ptr_a{ a };
    assignement_pointer<int> ptr_b{ b };

    std::swap(ptr_a, ptr_b);

    std::cout << "\nptrs = " << *ptr_a << ", " << *ptr_b << '\n';
    std::cout << "a, b = " << a << ", " << b << '\n';
}
```

and as this output shows:

```
move assignement constructor >> into >> move assignement operator
move assignement constructor >> into >> move assignement operator
swap()
move assignement constructor >> into >> move assignement operator
move assignement operator
move assignement operator

ptrs = 2, 3
a, b = 3, 2
```

it's that sitation that only the pointers are switched but not the original variables. `std::swap` is basically

```
_Ty _Tmp = _STD move(_Left);
_Left = _STD move(_Right);
_Right = _STD move(_Tmp);
```

explaining the

```
move assignement constructor >> into >> move assignement operator
move assignement operator
move assignement operator
```

the move assignement operator simply swaps the pointers so creating a temporary variable doesn't do anything. 
I see two possible solutions to this:

- make the move assignement operator not swap pointers but rather values.
- implement my own `swap()` for the class

but both don't work.

- the move assignement operator can't swap values because the initial `m_ptr` from `this->` class is always `nullptr` and I would rather not dereference this.
- `std::sort()` never uses `std::swap()` but instead just `std::move()`s from all over the place. (as already partially seen by `_Insertion_sort_unchecked`).

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  Why are you trying to get the variables outside the vector to change?  Is this a proof of concept or is there a situation you actually need this for?

Comment: ask this yourself: if you rip out the pages of a phone book and shuffle them, does this change anybodys phonenumber?

Comment: the behaviour of your first code is just what one would expect and tbh the rest is tl;dr

Comment: @NathanOliver with that I want to make a variadic template function that sorts the arguments. I could just copy them into a vector, sort the vector, and re-assign but I wondered if it is possible to just do it à la vector pointer

Comment: sure I know it tl;dr that's why I said that the last parts might be useless. But I would rather not keep the question that short so I provided my approach in solving this @user463035818

Comment: i didnt even find the part where you ask the question or where you explain the problem. It is really not clear what you want to achieve or how already existing answer to "How can I sort a vector of pointers?" do not apply

Comment: A better title would have been "How to sort pointed-to values?". Sorting pointers is something else (and is what you're doing already).

Comment: as I said, the first code is just as expected and then you write "In case anyone already knows the solution here, feel free to skip the next parts. I tried solving it with a workaround that is quite complicated. So in order to provid" but at that point it isnt clear yet what you are trying to solve

Comment: @user463035818 It wasn't clear, I edited it as rustyx pointed out. I am asking how I can sort a vector of pointers by value.

Comment: it seemed so easy, and I was surprised I just couldn't do it, no matter what I tried. It seems super complex and It's not like I want to make such a TL,DR but there's no way to explain this easily.

Comment: Because your explanation is wrong, you do not want to sort pointers by value, this is already done, you want `std::sort` to modify values where pointers in the `std::vector` point to. Ie you want references in your `std::vector`, not pointers

Comment: @Slava but references are just pointers? like literally

Comment: No, they are not. But unfortunately you cannot have references in `std::vector` and `std::reference_wrapper` does not work the way that would solve your problem.

Comment: please change the title because is misleading

Comment: yes @cprogrammer I am sorry. I mean it *was* a vector of pointers but that these pointers work like references is important to call. Although it would have been clear by reading the first code example... but still; misleading title.

Comment: Sorting an array of randomly scattered data (accessed via pointers) will slow down a sort. It would be faster to do a one time copy from the scattered data to a standard array or vector, do the sort, and a one time copy back to the scattered data.

Comment: @rcgldr i never thought about that, I might do some benchmarcking to observe. Good call.

Comment: @StackDanny - for the benchmark, create a vector of pointers (pointer[i] = &value[i]) to an vector of random values. Sort the vector of pointers according to the values using a lamda compare. Then assign a new set of random values using the now scrambled pointers, and do the custom sort that sorts the values referenced by the scrambled pointers. The size of the array or vector would need to be significantly larger than cache size, since cache will hide random access issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to roll your own sort function to do this.

The callback lambda is used to evaluate the ordering, but you need to tweak the part that does the actual exchange of elements: and the C++ standard library `sort` does not support your doing that.

Fortunately a *quick sort* without any bells and whistles (such as pre-randomisation) comes out in a few tens of lines, so this is not a particularly onerous task to complete.

Comment: Do you always reserve your answer timestamp to prevent people that do actual work from getting it first?

Comment: @Slava: You wot? It took me 22 minutes to respond to this.

Comment: I would expect somebody who says "You'll need to roll your own sort function to do this." to provide code sample. And somebody is probably already is working on it, but you get your answer first by simply saying, you need to do this, without providing actual answer. Same way you can put here "my answer will be here later, I am working on it"

Comment: @Slava: If you don't think this answer is useful then please downvote it. It's clear to me that the OP knows how to code judging by the question quality, so my job is to point out the approach. If you answer with code I'll be sure to upvote.

Comment: I found it demotivating when you are working on an answer but then see somebody answer it before you by typing "do it this way", and then modifying his answer to have actual answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba I suppose I never considered that is just not possible. I thought there must be some weird way. I mean I even tried to make my own std::move for the class to remove the && references or something but it boils down to the unavoidable logic that it's not possible.

Comment: @Slava: "and then modifying his answer to have actual answer" is a pretty serious accusation if it is executed by plagiarising another answer. If you observe that, then you ought to flag it to the moderators. If you have an answer then bang it up!

Comment: @StackDanny: I guess it's not possible since nobody has convinced the C++ standards committee that it might be useful.

Comment: I am not saying about "plagiarising", I am saying quite many people buy themselv time by typing short answer first and then working on actual one. I see it happens very often here.

Comment: @Slava: Well that's a dangerous game as you might attract a whole load of downvotes on the early drafts. Your opening comment was a strange one insofar that this answer came 22 minutes after the question was asked.

Comment: @Bathsheba that is the problem I do not quite understand benefits of "early drafts". So many people learned how to use or abuse the system, is it right way to go?

Comment: @Slava: You ought to raise a question on this topic on meta, if not a duplicate. Out of interest, where's you answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just retain a copy of the original vector of pointers and copy the sorted values over:

```
            std::vector<int*> original = vec;  // Do this before the std::sort
```

Then after you print a,b,c:

```
            std::vector<int> xfer;
            for (auto ptr : vec) {
                xfer.push_back(*ptr);
            }
            auto it = std::begin(xfer);
            for (auto ptr : original) {
                *ptr = *it++;
            }
            std::cout << "abc = " << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << '\n';
```

Output:

```
abc = 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: well if I do it like this, I don't even need pointers at all as I can just copy - sort - copyback which is what I commented I would rather not do. But given that my original idea is not possible, I do either this or make my own sort. So in the end it's a question of performance vs maintainability between Bathsheba's answer and yours.